# angular Todo get request wont populate page

Tags: node.js, angular, api, http

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kmw3.png)

I am following some tutorials while i do this, but im not sure where problem is coming from. I keep getting a blank page. I want the list of todos fetched from the database displayed.  I am using the todoservice to fetch data from the api and the the app component subscribes to the data to be rendered on the app.component.

What am i not doing correctly?

here's the code

./app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoServiceService } from './todo-service.service';
import {Todo} from './todo-model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      
  public todos: any = [];
    
  constructor(private _todoService: TodoServiceService){}
      
  ngOnInit() {
    this._todoService.getTodos()
    .subscribe(data => this.todos = data)
  }
}
```

./todo-service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ Todo } from './todo-model';
import{ Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoServiceService {
  private url= "http://localhost:4000/home";
    
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
    
  getTodos(): Observable<Todo>{
    return this._http.get<Todo>(this.url);
  }
}
```

./todo.components.html

```html
<ul *ngFor="let todo of todos">
  <li>{{todo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is your backend server running on `4000` port?

Comment: yes running on port 4000

Answer (score 0):

you should add a `console.log()` or a `debugger` brakepoint in order to debug your code. Also you should catch your error:

```js
this._todoService.getTodos().subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(datas);
    this.todos = data;
    debugger; // in alternative to console.log
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```